# How to automate text selection in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to automate the following task in tmux:

- enter copy mode
- move the cursor up X lines
- select Y lines above the cursor
- yank those lines

Is this feasible? How?

I was able to enter copy mode via `:copy-mode` but then I don't know how to proceed.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in the while.

**Note: I have this option set in .tmux.conf that states that the keys hjkl should be used to move the cursor as in vim:**

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```

I created a separate file which I named copy-that.tmux. 
It contains those lines:

```
copy-mode
send-keys kkkkkkkkkkkk
send-keys 0
send-keys v
send-keys jjjjjjjj
send-keys $
send-keys y
```

First line enters copy mode, the following move the cursor up. You can also use

```
send-keys Up
```

If you don't have vim-mode keys, but I wasn't able to find a way to put several of those in a single line. 
Then I move to the beginning of the line with '0', enter visual mode with 'v', go down with 'j', move to the end of the line with $, and finally yank the text with 'y'.

Then I bound the execution of the script in .tmux.conf:
    bind -n F6 run "/path/to/copy-that.tmux"